# Failure initializing submodules from a bare repo cloned from an rsync'd repo

Tags: git, rsync, git-submodules

I'm having a problem initializing submodules after a convoluted process of setting up the repository:

1. Clone a remote bare repo with submodules.
2. Initialize and update submodules in this repo. Everything is cool here.
3. Create a local bare repo by cloning the non-bare local repo. (I said convoluted, right?)
4. rsync this repo to machine X (which does not have access to the original remote)
5. Make a non-bare clone the rsync'd repo on machine X.
6. Attempt to initialize and update the sub-modules on the new repo.

The result of step six:

```
fatal: repository '/some/dir/foo.git' does not exist
```

The superproject directory was cloned into /some/dir/project/.

The process is so convoluted because: step 1 is painfully slow and machine X has no access to the original repository because of networking restrictions.

So within these constraints (I could re-do step 1, if necessary, perhaps creating a local bare repository straight away) is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to do here?

Thanks.

Comment: `.gitmodules` is more what you'd call "guidelines" than actual rules.  My first attempt would be to also rsync the submodule repos to the step-4 machine, `git config submodule.modulename.url url://step-4/path/to/subrepo` in the step-6 repo for each submodule, and retry the submodule updates.

Comment: This does the trick. I modified your suggestion to create a bare clone of a submodule repo from the master rsync'ed repository. (Since it recursively included all of the submodules) Then setting submodule.foo.url to this location allowed me to update the repository.  If you want to promote your comment to an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.gitmodules` is more what you'd call "guidelines" than actual rules.

My first attempt would be

- also rsync the submodule repos to the step-4 machine, and
- in the step-6 repo, for each submodule,

  - `git config submodule.modulename.url url://step-4/path/to/subrepo`
- retry the submodule updates